MariaDB sporadically dropping connections from an Apache module on RHEL9/Fedora
I have a custom apache module that handles authentication/authorisation via a MySQL/MariaDB database. This module has worked quite happily for more than a decade on a variety of Linux platforms in development, staging and production environments.
The module makes a number of database queries to check the user credentials and access rights for each incoming request, and approves or denies access accordingly.
I’m trying to set up some new production servers with RHEL 9.4, using the stock  MariaDB 10.5.23 that comes with that. The database server is up and running and working fine alongside the old RHEL 7 web server.
I’m now trying to get an RHEL 9.4 web server up and running to replace the old one, but the authentication module is no longer working correctly. It handles the majority of requests just fine, but I’m seeing sporadic MariaDB failures where the connection to the server is dropping.
If I load a web page that pulls in a bunch of resources (CSS, JS, images etc), several of those requests (maybe 10% or so) fail due to a database connection error. This happens even if I first restart both apache and MariaDB, so it's not a problem with stale connections.
On the client side I’m seeing errors like:
Lost connection to server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 9
Lost connection to server at 'sending authentication information', system error: 104
Got packets out of order
Server has gone away

And on the server side:
[Warning] Aborted connection 285 to db: ‘xxx’ user: ‘xxx’ host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)

I can also replicate this problem in my local development environment using Fedora, with web server and database running in a single VM. (It’s been working just fine on Ubuntu).
I don’t think it’s a problem with the DB setup - that’s been running happily in production for a couple of months now with the old web server. I think it must be a problem with the client.
The module has been built on exactly the same platform RHEL/Fedora as the database is running, so it doesn’t seem like there should be an incompatibility between versions.
It could, of course, be a bug in the module code, but I’ve pored over it extensively, and I’m not seeing anything.
I’ve tried increasing various variables in the DB (max packet size, timeouts, etc) just in case I was suddenly hitting some limit, but that doesn’t seem to be case.
I’m at a bit of a loss as to what to try next. Does anyone have any ideas? Any clues where to look next?
